# scala - create a mutable map and with default value as (0,0) if key not exist

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. As title, I would like to create a mutable map `Map[Int,(Int, Int)]` and with default value as tuple (0,0) if key not exist. In python the "defaultdict" make such effort easy. what is the elegant way to do it in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `withDefaultValue` after creating the map:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val map = mutable.Map[Int,(Int, Int)]().withDefaultValue((0, 0))
```

Comment: Nice solution! Another naive question, I changed the tuple to Array to make its element increment-able like this map(0)+=1 . But the statement var map = mutable.Map[Int,Array[Int, Int]]().withDefaultValue(Array[0, 0]) cause error

Comment: Try `var map = mutable.Map[Int,Array[(Int, Int)]]().withDefaultValue(Array((0, 0)))` if you want it to be an array of _tuples_. Or `var map = mutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]]().withDefaultValue(Array(0))` if you want it to be an array of _ints_.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need! var map = mutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]]().withDefaultValue(Array(0,0))

Answer (score 2):

you are probably lookign for `.getOrElseUpdate` which takes the key, if not present updates with given value.

```
scala> val googleMap = Map[Int, (Int, Int)]().empty
googleMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,(Int, Int)] = Map()

scala> googleMap.getOrElseUpdate(100, (0, 0))
res3: (Int, Int) = (0,0)

scala> googleMap
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,(Int, Int)] = Map(100 -> (0,0))
```

You can also pass the `orElse` part implicitly,

```
scala> implicit val defaultValue = (0, 0)
defaultValue: (Int, Int) = (0,0)

scala> googleMap.getOrElseUpdate(100, implicitly)
res8: (Int, Int) = (0,0)

scala> googleMap
res9: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,(Int, Int)] = Map(100 -> (0,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

withDefaultValue is much simpler than getOrElseUpdate.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

var kv1 = mutable.Map[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
var kv2 = mutable.Map[Int, Int]()

kv1(1) += 5 // use default value when key is not exists

kv1(2) = 3

kv2(2) = 3 // both can assign value to a new key.

println(f"kv1(1) ${kv1(1)}, kv1(2) ${kv1(2)} " )
println(f"kv1 ${kv1}")

kv2.getOrElseUpdate(1, 18) // set a default if key not exists
println(f"kv2(1) ${kv2(1)}, kv2(2) ${kv2(2)}")
println(f"kv2 ${kv2}")
```

Output:

kv1(1) 5, kv1(2) 3

kv1 Map(2 -> 3, 1 -> 5)

kv2(1) 18, kv2(2) 3

kv2 Map(2 -> 3, 1 -> 18)